# Make a Field Mandatory on the Graph Level

Tags: attributes, field, acumatica, dac

Newbie to Acumatica here. I've performed a small amount of customization to our system, and am now diving into adding custom data fields.

My goal is to synchronize hardware shipment information from Acumatica into our legacy (outdated and proprietary) hardware management system, as we will need to continue using this system for the time being for warranty calculations. I plan to eventually build this into Acumatica.

My current issue is that I need a method of associating [Customer Locations](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(9))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=61a8c6de-6a51-434b-8c2d-4304ec982ae0) to the customer locations in our legacy system. Adding the field `DCL_ID` was easy enough to accomplish following the [To Add a Custom Data Field](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(9))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=5a2bddc7-dd58-4de4-a9f5-f4d5ce073b77) documentation. I made the column be required by setting

```
[PXDefault]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="DCL Account ID", Required = true)]
```

to the attributes section of the Data Access class [as outlined here](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(9))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=97f5b92f-906a-4edd-ae38-f5605e83d845).  I then added the field to my form using the **Layout Editor**.

At this point all seemed well. The field shows an asterisk in the UI and also validates that a value is provided. Then I realized that **Customer Locations** is not the only place that uses `CR.Location` -- it is also used by [Account Locations](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(9))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=c5ea5417-5461-438a-b9bf-191c6d554798). Doing some digging I've found that **Account Locations** can include many more account types than **Customer Locations**. I only need this attribute to be required for **Customer Locations**. Thus, I have opted to use the [To Make a Field Mandatory on the Graph Level](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(9))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=97f5b92f-906a-4edd-ae38-f5605e83d845).

Here is my `CustomerLocationMaint` code:

```cs
using System;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.AR;

namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
  public class CustomerLocationMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<CustomerLocationMaint>
  {
    #region Event Handlers

    [PXDefault]
    [PXCustomizeBaseAttribute(typeof(PXUIFieldAttribute), "Required", true)]
    protected virtual void SelectedCustomerLocation_UsrDCL_ID_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
    {

    }

    #endregion
  }
}
```

After I save and publish the customization, the field does not function as a required field, as it did when I defined the requirements at the DAC level.

[image]

So, what have I done wrong? I've read and re-read the documentation multiple times, but cannot find my mistake.

**Setup:**
[image: CR.Location]

[image: Layout Editor: AR303020]

[image: CustomerLocationMaint]

Comment: could be the underscore in the field name causing the cache attached to not properly register the graph level attribute change? Try using a field name without the underscore. The documentation mentions this should be avoided as listed here: https://help.acumatica.com/Wiki/(W(2))/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=5659adfe-3e4a-45a6-a94a-a33c2f955194

Comment: @Brendan That fixed it! If you could post that as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. There are other areas this could cause issues with too so good to catch it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thought is the underscore in the field name causing the cache attached to not properly register the graph level attribute change. Using a field name without the underscore is the preferred naming convention for tables and columns.

The Acumatica documentation mentions this should be avoided as listed here:
[Database Design Guidelines](https://help.acumatica.com/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=5659adfe-3e4a-45a6-a94a-a33c2f955194)

Found under **Table and Column Naming Conventions**:

> Do not use the underscore symbol (_) in table or column names, because
>   it is a reserved symbol in Acumatica Framework. For example,
>   CompanyType is a valid column name, while Company_Type is invalid.